# Calculation of trace of linear map $u\mapsto\frac{1}{|G|}\sum\limits_{g\in G} \chi(g^{-1})gu$

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory, representation-theory

Let $G$ be a finite group, $V$ a $\mathbb{C}G$-module with character $\chi$. Let $z:=\frac{1}{|G|}\sum\limits_{g\in G}\chi(g^{-1})g\in\mathbb{C}G$. Let $U$ be an irreducible $\mathbb{C}G$-module with characer $\psi$. We define $\zeta:U\to U$ by $\zeta(u)=zu$. It is easy to show that $\zeta$ is  $\mathbb{C}G$-homomorphism. By Schur's lemma, there exists $\lambda\in\mathbb{C}$ such that $\zeta(u)=\lambda u$. Then Tr$_U(\zeta)=\lambda\dim(U)$. Now my question asks to calculate Tr$_U(\zeta)$ in terms of $\psi $ and $\chi$. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By definition the trace of $g$ acting on $U$ is $\psi(g)$. So the trace of
$\frac1{|G|}\sum_{g\in G}\chi(g^{-1})g$ acting on $U$ is
$$\frac1{|G|}\sum_{g\in G}\chi(g^{-1})\psi(g).$$
This is an integer, the number of copies of the irreducible module $U$
within the module $V$.